# How to set image upload size for tinyMce?

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm using [@tinymce/tinymce-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-angular) and I'm trying to set limit for image upload.
I tried to use `images_upload_handler` as mentioned at [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#example). 
Here is my code

```
  imagesUploadHandler = (blobInfo, success, failure) => {    
    const size = blobInfo.blob().size;
    // Just for testing I set small size
    if (size > 100) {
      failure('error');
    } 
    console.log(size);

  }
```

The problem is that I see error message about size limitation but image is added into tinyMce. How can prevent image adding on failure ?

Example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/a-tinymce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `BeforeSetContent` event. Before setting content need to check if content type is blob then we can find image blob information in `editorUpload.blobCache`.

```
  setup = editor => {
    editor.on('BeforeSetContent', e => {
      // e.content = <img src="blob:http://localhost:4200/:id" />
      if (e.content && e.content.includes('blob:')) {
        const s = e.content
          .substr(e.content.indexOf('blob'), e.content.length)
          .replace('/>', '')
          .replace('>', '')
          .replace('"', '')
          .trim();
        if (e.target.editorUpload.blobCache.getByUri(s)) {
          let size = e.target.editorUpload.blobCache.getByUri(s).blob().size;
          const allowedSize = 10; // KB
          size = size / 1024; // KB
          if (size > allowedSize) {
            console.log('Max size Error');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/a-tinymce)